# using promise to set function order

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a 4 functions, I would like to set them in order running first to fourth.

this is my current code

**code**

```
Promise.all([firstFunction(), secondFunction()])
    .then(thirdFunction);
    .then(fouthFunction);
```

**Question**

Is this the correct way to run function 1 and 2 then 3 then 4 ?

Comment: The question is kinda vague, what do you specifically want to know?

Comment: Can you elaborate more the question? I mean, are your functions sync or async? Do they return promises or they use callback? Do they need the previous functions return values?

Comment: sorry guys updated

Comment: Short answer is yes but you should provide more context, specifically async vs sync. Otherwise what's the point for the promises? This also runs the functions in order: `a(); b(); c(); d();`

Comment: needs to be async as function 3 and 4 relay on the outcome of 1 and 2

Comment: so @beep that is correct as I say you in the response.

Comment: @F.bernal almost, I fixed it with `Promise.all([firstFunction(), secondFunction()])
    .then(thirdFunction) .then(fourthFunction);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I had to lay out my code as follows then it worked.

Not sure why +1 to anyone who can explain why.

```
    Promise.all([firstFunction(),
    secondFunction()]) .then(thirdFunction) .then(fourthFunction);
```

Comment: Because in your initial code you must remove the ; after .then(thirdFunction);

Answer (score 0):

```
Promise.all([firstFunction(), secondFunction()])
    .then(thirdFunction)
    .then(fouthFunction);
```

This execute thirdFunction when first and second functions are their promises fullfiled and fourthFuction will be executed when thrirdFuction promise is fullfiled.

So, yes. They will be executed in order third and fourth after first and second.

If you want ensure this the order 1, 2, 3, 4 just do this...

first().then(second).then(third).then(fourth) this is in order taking into account that they are fullfiled (resolved correctly) if you want to execute the next one, althought the previous one is rejected... you need to manage that case.

Comment: Not what the OP is asking.

Comment: He is asking about order execution, so its function 3 and 4 are executed in order.

Comment: You can tell that now, but at the moment you sent the reply,  the question was merely a "how would I do this correctly ?"

Comment: @Fondor I reply with what I see... I don't know why are we talking about this :S

Comment: Don't try to fool me. At the moment you wrote the first version of your answer you know the question was formulated differently that it is now.